# Trigger for capturing changed columns in audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables, one main table and one audit table.

```
create sequence dbo.users_seq;
create table dbo.users 
(
 id bigint primary key default(next value for dbo.users_seq),
 name varchar(100) not null, --user's full name
 user_data nvarchar(max) not null check(isjson(user_data) = 1),
 timestamp datetime2 not null default sysdatetime(),
 updated_timestamp datetime2 not null default sysdatetime()
);

create sequence dbo.users_audit_seq;
create table dbo.users_audit
(
 id bigint primary key default(next value for dbo.users_audit_seq),
 users_id bigint not null, --id from `users` table
 old nvarchar(max) not null check(isjson(old) = 1), --original row from `users` table
 new nvarchar(max) not null check(isjson(new) = 1), --new row from `users` table
 query varchar(max) not null, --query used for update
 updated_by varchar(100) not null, --username info
 timestamp datetime2 not null default sysdatetime()
);
```

I am looking to create an `after update` trigger on `users` main table that could be used for capturing changed columns (excluding timestamps) in `users_audit` table. *(Example below)*

I am able to manually do this through `json_modify()` and `OPENJSON(@json` but unable to get it working automatically through a trigger

Initial insert:

| id | name | user_data | timestamp | updated_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | {"email":"jdoe@abc.com"} | 2021-05-08 18:10:02.0474381 | 2021-05-08 18:10:02.0474381 |

Sample update:

| id | name | user_data | timestamp | updated_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | {"email":"jdoe@abc.com","address":"123 Main St"} | 2021-05-08 18:10:02.0474381 | 2021-05-08 18:12:06.0474381 |

After the above update audit table should look like:

| id | users_id | old | new | query | updated_by | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"name":"John","user_data":{"email":"jdoe@abc.com"}} | {"name":"John Doe","user_data":{"email":"jdoe@abc.com","address":"123 Main St"}} | *update query* | *username* | 2021-05-08 18:12:06.0474381 |

Sample update 2:

| id | name | user_data | timestamp | updated_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | {"email":"jdoe@abc.com","address":"123 Main St"} | 2021-05-08 18:10:02.0474381 | 2021-05-08 18:14:16.0474381 |

After the above update2 audit table should look like:
(`old` and `new` not capturing *user_data* as it hasn't changed)

| id | users_id | old | new | query | updated_by | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"name":"John","user_data":{"email":"jdoe@abc.com"}} | {"name":"John Doe","user_data":{"email":"jdoe@abc.com","address":"123 Main St"}} | *update query* | *username* | 2021-05-08 18:12:06.0474381 |
| 2 | 1 | {"name":"John Doe"} | {"name":"John"} | *update query* | *username* | 2021-05-08 18:14:16.0474381 |

Note : *Temporal tables* or *SQL Audit* approaches won't work

Comment: Please have a go and post a question when stuck. The official documentation for SQL Server has lots of great information and example on building triggers as do many other tutorials available. However we are not going to write it for you.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I did have a go but if you see this requires capturing info as json key value pairs which is where I'm stuck (rather than the trigger creation itself).

Comment: How is this different from your previous two questions? Other than the need to do a nested `FOR JSON` subquery, it seems almost exactly the same and also no attempt

Comment: @Charlieface, yes the json part is the difference. I am new here and I didn't want to change the question there since it already had responses and I read on guidelines that it's better to post new question instead of editing once it has been answered.

Comment: @DaleK I am new here and still looking for help. My original question was posted yesterday and I have been trying to get that to work with `json_modify()` using by following this tutorial https://www.sqlshack.com/modifying-json-data-using-json_modify-in-sql-server/ and integrating that with a trigger doesn't seem very straightforward.

Comment: We realise you are new, thats why we keep giving you advice :) but you're not taking it. There is no code in your current question :)

Comment: You need to show your actual json_modify and openjson code, else how can we help you fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

The principles are mostly the same as mentioned on an earlier answer. The main differences are:

- Get the starting batch using `dm_exec_input_buffer`. You need server-level permissions for this.
- `FOR JSON` will not show a key which has a `NULL` value, so we can use `SELECT...EXCEPT` to remove values which are the same between `inserted` and `deleted`.
- `JSON_QUERY` is necessary to prevent double-escaping of existing JSON objects

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_users ON users
AFTER UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;  -- prevent issues with bad client drivers

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    RETURN;  -- early bail-out
    
-- needs sa permissions
DECLARE @inputBuf nvarchar(max) /* = (
    SELECT b.event_info
    FROM sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@SPID, NULL) b
);*/

INSERT users_audit (users_id, old, new, query, updated_by)
SELECT
  i.id,
  (
      SELECT
          -- SELECT EXCEPT will null this out if they are the same
        name = (SELECT i.name EXCEPT SELECT d.name),
        user_data = JSON_QUERY((SELECT i.user_data EXCEPT SELECT d.user_data))
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ),
  (
      SELECT
        name = (SELECT d.name EXCEPT SELECT i.name),
        user_data = JSON_QUERY((SELECT d.user_data EXCEPT SELECT i.user_data))
      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ),
  ISNULL(@inputBuf, ''),
  SUSER_SNAME()
FROM inserted i
JOIN deleted d ON d.id = i.id  -- join to match by all primary key columns
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT i.name, i.user_data    -- add other columns here
    INTERSECT             -- because INTERSECT deals correctly with nulls
    SELECT d.name, d.user_data
);

go
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b665cc88c8e5675f32cfd1cfb3972bab)

Comment: In the interests of full disclosure, I think this is reinventing the wheel on behalf of OP, but I'm bored. And OP should really make an attempt themselves.